# Implement derived class in Python while the base class be coded in C++

Tags: python, c++, boost-python, pybind11, python-cffi

I have built a soft platform. It supports many "Widget" running on it. The platform is a Linux natural C++ application. The so-called "Widgets" are all derived class of one same base class, and
implement a same API, linked into many *.so file respectively(one Widget live in one so). The platform loads Widget by calling `dlopen( "widget_name.so" )`, and runs one Widget in one thread.
When I implement many Widgets in C++, everything is OK so far, but now I need let my platform can run/support Widgets those be coded in Python by other programmers(They are not familiar with C++).

I studied [embedding-python-in-c](https://docs.python.org/zh-cn/3/extending/embedding.html#embedding-python-in-c) and [CFFI](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#embedding), but they mainly talk about calling/linking Python with C, and I can't find any information about "How to implement derived class in Python that inherited from a base in C++".

My question is:

1. Can I implement such a derived class in Python while its base class coded in C++?
2. Can these derived class in Python call/interact with other objects in C++?

Sorry for my ugly English, it's not my mother tongue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the base class being in C++...? Just export the C++ class as Python, other classes can subclass that class as usual.

Comment: [1. Extending Python with C or C++ — Python 3.9.7 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html)

Comment: @user202729 Thanks for hints. you mean that I should call c++ in Python? No! My core engine must be coded with C++, Python is so slow! Python are used only at prototype stage.

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting, no?

Comment: If my platform be implemented with Python, the performanc of whole system will be slow,  though most of Widgets is coded with C++. That is unacceptable.

Comment: So what is your question? If you *did benchmark* the program and find that the *existing* Python code is slow, then reimplement it in C++. (there are other options to make Python faster, such as numpy or numba)

Comment: Oh, my platform had been implemented, with C++. The requirement about supporting Python Widgets is received recently.

Comment: I think what you want should be "how python binding to C++" and let c++ to execute python code.

Comment: @LouisGo Yes, it is what I want. Further more, I want inherit a c++ base class in Python.